# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS .run file issues

Tags: 14.04, files

Having some Issues with the .run type files. I've looked all over the place to try and make them work and they just open with gedit. The window Freezes and stops responding. Even giving the file permission to execute as a program doesn't work... can anyone Help me?

Answer (score 0):

`.run` files should be ran in a terminal window.  If you are double clicking them from Nautilus, there is a good chance that they are defaulting to <kbd>Display</kbd> which will open the `gedit` application and try to bring you to an edit window, but usually these type of files are so large they will overrun the buffer of `gedit` and cause it to hang.

To execute `.run` files, first open a terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> all at the same time.

To make the `.run` file executable from the terminal window, type in

```
chmod +x /path/to/filename.run
```

then to execute the file, type in

```
/path/to/filename.run
```

or if you are already in the same folder as the `.run` file, type in

```
./filename.run
```

Try to avoid running or double clicking on `.run` files from the graphical environment as much as possible.